# How to prevent model mapper to not map the lazy loaded collection in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I am making a rest api using `Spring Boot`, `Spring Data JPA` and mysql. I have user and role entity. User can have many roles and roles can have many users. I am ModelMapper dependency for converting entity to DTO.

I have set the roles collection fetch type to lazy. But ModelMapper is calling the `getRoles()` method on user entity. How to stop it.

*Note: User and UserDTO has same fields.*

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String username;
private String password;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Role Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String roleName;
}
```

UserService Class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private ModelMapper mapper; 
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public UserDTO find(Integer id){
   User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
   return mapper.map(user,UserDTO.class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can applied a conditional skip operation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729404/2039546

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
TypeMap<User, UserDTO> typeMap = modelMapper
        .createTypeMap(User.class, UserDTO.class);
// Create empty list condition for JPA.
Condition<Object, Object> emptyListCondition = mc ->
        (!(mc.getSource() instanceof PersistentCollection) 
                || ((PersistentCollection) mc.getSource())
                .wasInitialized());
// Add mappings.
typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper
        .when(emptyListCondition)
        .map(User::getRoles, UserDTO::setRoles));

// Test.
UserDTO userDTO = modelMapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);
```

Comment: I am using entity graph adhoc for it

Comment: It works with the same logic, just a different strategy.

Comment: So do I need to make my own function for mapping?

Comment: If we write a custom control in `JPA` it will work for you. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare a skip property.

Example:

```
TypeMap<Game, GameDTO> propertyMapper = this.mapper.createTypeMap(Game.class, GameDTO.class);
propertyMapper.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(GameDTO::setId));
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper

Comment: I want modelmapper to skip it dynamically i.e if roles set is loaded then map it and if roles set is not loaded then do not map it.